# How to tie Work Items to a release that have no code

Tags: configuration, project, requirements

Setting Up ADO ALERT (New user)

Is there a way to link a work item (say Feature) to an Azure Devops Release, where there work items are manual configurations?  I like the Relase management in ADO, but don't need to compile code in this project.

Any ideas?

Jeff

I tried creating a release pipeline with a deployment to our staging, but I couldn't figure out how to turn off the jobs or how to configure the changeset/builds in order to get the work item linked to the build (which is manual config) and linked to the Release.